# Heroku build fails in prod but not locally

Tags: reactjs, heroku, build, dependencies

I am fairly new to Heroku and I am having an issue trying to do an automated build from github.  A had previously performed builds through the cli but I was hoping to eliminate that step and have heroku get the updates directly from github.

To complicate matters I am using a template that I purchased so there is more stuff going on than I am used to seeing.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
 npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
       npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.9.2" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer @material-ui/core@"4.0.1" from material-table@1.69.2
```

This is the error in the heroku log.

```
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  15.5.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  1.22.10
       
       Resolving node version 15.5.0...
       Downloading and installing node 15.5.0...
       Using default npm version: 7.3.0
       Resolving yarn version 1.22.10...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.10)
       Installed yarn 1.22.10
```

I can see that it is picking up the values from my "engines" entry.  These match my dev setup.  Does 'npm' indicate that it is not using yarn?  I am using yarn locally and there is a yarn.lock file.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix .",
```

This is the scripts area of package.json.

Comment: I did manage to make some progress on this.  Most of the libraries that caused an issue were secondary and included in package.json by the maker of the template.  Still poking through them.

Answer (score 0):

Comfirm you are not using environmental variables in development which you haven't added in heroku

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Yup, brand new heroku app with absolutely no variables set there.  I was trying to get an initial build accomplish.  There is one thing which I just realized - it didn't initially fail the build in Heroku - I was getting an error with the express server when I tried to load the page.  Then I started getting build failures - not sure what changed since the app is still just a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Once I remembered that the builds used to work I went back and looked at the changes.  I forgot that I had added in the "engines" to tell Heroku what versions of node to use.  Once I let it choose its own version again the builds worked.  I went back to the template authors to see which versions they are using.